# extrude between two point in a curve

Tags: modeling, mesh, bezier-curves

How can i extrude a new point in a curve between two points without creating a new point

[image: I try to extrude but it creates two points. I want to make a joint pipe using curves** **]

Comment: I guess this sort of answers your question: [Problem with joining Bezier curves in blender 3.5.1](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/294025/problem-with-joining-bezier-curves-in-blender-3-5-1). At least if your goal is to create a branch extruding from a spline segment: control points on a spline can only have one or two connections: one, if they are the endpoint of a spline or two, if they are somewhere inbetween a spline. Never three or more - a spline cannot branch somewhere. It always has one start point and an end point, and optionally some number of control points between them.

Comment: Hi, joseph, welcome. At first sight, this does look like a duplicate. If we're wrong, please go ahead and edit to clarify exactly what you mean, an why the suggested link is unsatisfactory. Then we can re-open your post, and give it our best shot.